# Scroll GuiTableControl object to find the row with a specific value in a given column

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have created an Excel spreadsheet that extracts live data from a query in SAP GUI and paste that info back into Excel

[image: Extraction Pic]

From there, I'm opening transaction `ME38` to update schedule lines based off the extracted data.  I need to go to the "scheduled.." column (which I know to be "`txtEKET-MENGE`") and change the number shown to the "Qty Delivered" (which is a part of the extraction); however, I need to only do this on certain cells in the "Schedule..." column ("`txtEKET-ETENR`") [data listed on extraction as well].

[image: SAP Table Pic]

When it gets to "Set grid..." it ends the function and does nothing else.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I've done so far.

```
Set xclapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xclwbk = ThisWorkbook
Set xclsht = xclwbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
For k = 2 To ActiveCell.SpecialCells(11).Row
For j = 1 To ActiveCell.SpecialCells(11).Column
If j = 14 Then Purch = xclsht.Cells(k, j).Value
If j = 15 Then Item = xclsht.Cells(k, j).Value
If j = 16 Then SLine = xclsht.Cells(k, j).Value
If j = 8 Then PGI = xclsht.Cells(k, j).Value
Next
myTransaction = "ME38"

Session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/n" & myTransaction

Session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

On Error Resume Next
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRM06E-EVRTN").Text = Purch
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRM06E-EVRTN").caretPosition = 10
Session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRM06E-EBELP").Text = Item
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRM06E-EBELP").caretPosition = 3
Session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[30]").press
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[2]").press
Call SelectRowOnGrid
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[0]").Select
Session.FindById("wnd[0]").Close
  On Error Resume Next

  Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-OPTION1").press
Next
End If
If Err.Number <> 0 Then

'The Excel worksheet has e.g. 3 columns of data and an error column.

xclsht.Cells(j, 21).Value = "Here is an error."

Else

xclsht.Cells(j, 21).Value = "O.K."

End If

On Error GoTo 0
```

The following is the Function SelectRowOnGrid.

```
Function SelectRowOnGrid()
Dim grid As SAPFEWSELib.GuiTableControl
Dim columnname As SAPFEWSELib.GuiTableColumn
Dim texttofind As String
Set grid = Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06ETC_1117/")
Set columnname = Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06ETC_1117/txtEKET-  ETENR")
texttofind = xclsht.Cells(k, 16).Value

    For k = 0 To grid.RowCount - 1

If grid.GetCellValue(k, columnname) = texttofind Then
grid.SetCurrentCell
grid.DoubleClickCurrentCell
End If

    Next k

End Function
```

Comment: First I would find the correct column name. For example, use the script recorder to record a script by simply highlighting the relevant column and terminating the recording at that point. The column name you are looking for is in the recorded script.

Comment: Right.  Let me paraphrase.

I need code that scrolls through SAP table column Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06ETC_1117/txtEKET-ETENR) to look for a particular number (from Excel spreadsheet).  Once it locates the particular number, I need it to update the data in column 

Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06ETC_1117/txtEKET-MENGE) to a different number on the same Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example of how to deal with a table in SAP. In your case you use the commands for a GRID and this is not correct.

for example:

```
myFile = "z:\tmp\test.xlsx"
mySheet = "Test"

Set xclApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xclwbk = xclapp.Workbooks.Open(myFile)
set xclsht = xclwbk.Sheets(mySheet)

xclApp.Visible = True
xclapp.DisplayAlerts = false

k = 1

do

set myTable = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE")

 if k = 1 then
 'rows = myTable.RowCount
  cols = myTable.Columns.Count
  vRows = myTable.VisibleRowCount
  for j = 0 to cols - 1
   xclsht.Cells(k,j + 1).Value = myTable.columns.elementAt(j).title
  next
  k = k + 1
 end if

for i = 0 to vRows - 1
l = 1
 for j = 0 to Cols - 1
  on error resume next
  myVariable = trim(myTable.GetCell(i,j).Text) 
  if err.number <> 0 then  exit for      
  on error goto 0
  if left(right(myVariable,3),1) = "," then 
   myVariable = replace(myVariable, "." , "")
   myVariable = replace(myVariable, "," , "")
   xclsht.Cells(k,l).Value = myVariable/100
  else 
   xclsht.Cells(k,l).Value = myVariable 
  end if
  l = l + 1
 next
 if err.number <> 0 then  exit for       
 k = k + 1
next
if err.number <> 0 then  exit do       
myTable.VerticalScrollbar.Position = myTable.VerticalScrollbar.Position + vRows

Loop 
xclapp.ActiveWorkbook.Save

Set xclwbk = Nothing
Set xclsheet = Nothing
set xclapp = Nothing
```

Regards,
ScriptMan

Comment: Scriptman, Thank you so much for providing this information.  While it didn't directly solve my problem, it helped me learn and deduce a resolution to my problem.  Very much appreciate the assistance and my new found knowledge.  Sincerely, Josh

Comment: Josh, I am very glad it helped. Sometimes it is better to find a solution by itself. ;-)