# Automatic Scroll SAP GUI

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I'm trying to scroll until the end of the page and I recorded a script and did some changes. I thought of something like that

```
For i = 1 To END_PAGE

    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").setCurrentCell i, "AUFNR"

Next
```

Where "AUFNR" is the name of the column I'm analyzing. But how do I know the END_PAGE if the code stops working when it checks a line it doesn't exist?

Here is a screenshot of the table I'm analyzing in SAP GUI

[image]

For example I could verify if EACH element has a text but unfortunely I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a "`GuiGridView` Object". There's public documentation in SAP Web site. Did you already check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721733/scroll-guigridview-to-find-the-row-with-a-specific-value-in-a-given-column)? If yes, what did you try, what doesn't work?

Comment: I did try but I get "the object does not accept property or method" in the line Cols = myTable.Columns.Count

Comment: If I knew how to verifiy text in each cell from a colum it would solve my problem once for all

Comment: My bad, I was mistaken by the title of that answer, which was referring in fact to a `GuiTableControl` object, and yours is a `GuiGridView` object. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576298/cant-read-all-rows-from-guigridview-getting-blank-after-34-rows) should be better, it's for a `GuiGridView` object "for sure", but in fact I have a doubt because you are now talking about columns, so I'm not sure what you are asking.